# Is it safe to move this EFI partition?

Tags: ubuntu, partition, dual-boot, uefi, gparted

My configuration:

```
/dev/sdb2/ -> Windows 10 Partition
/dev/sdb4/ -> Ubuntu 18.04 Partition
```

[image]

I would like to decrease the Windows 10 partition and give that unallocated space to the Ubuntu 18 partition, **but there is an EFI (boot, esp) partition between them**. What is the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot a Linux Live CD from USB and run `gparted` again. You can't resize your root partition while it is being mounted (the lock symbol).

Steps to do:

1. Resize the Windows partition "to the left", the freed space should be on the right side.
2. Move the ESP partition "to the left", so that the free space "is moved" from the left to the right side.
3. Resize the root partition.

Comment: Does it can brake the boot?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. The partitions are the same before and after the operation, only the start and end positions are different. But you should backup your data before you do anything to the partitions.